# PHP - Plain Text Page Break

Tags: php, plaintext, page-break

I am creating an export system that can do multiple formats and one of them is plain text. I want the headers with the column name to appear at the top of each page when the document is printed. Is there a way I could force a page break in plain text. I have only found ways to to this in HTML/CSS. The output format for the file looks something like this:

```
+----------+----------------+
| Column 1 |    Column 2    |
+----------+----------------+
| Data     | More Data      |
+----------+----------------+
| Data     | More Data      |
+----------+----------------+
| Data     | More Data      |
+----------+----------------+
```

Answer (score 3):

You could try sending an ASCII [form feed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break) which is character 0xC.  If the text is sent directly to a printer, then that character will force the printer to eject the page.